# How to avoid calling `awakeFromNib` twice when view uses a separate `xib` for its TouchBar

Tags: swift, macos, xib, nstouchbar

## Background

I'm adding a TouchBar to an app. I have a few window controllers that should use the same TouchBar design, adopt the same protocol (say `AddWindowCommon`), and are designed in their own `xib` file.

I designed my TouchBar in a separate `xib` file (`AddWindowTouchBar`). This way I can set the file to only compile on macOS 10.12.2+ (the versions that support the TouchBar) while the rest of the project deploys on macOS 10.9+. The file owner adopts the `AddWindowCommon` protocol and the touchbar keeps a weak reference to it to function properly. Then, to use this touchbar, I override the `makeTouchBar` as such:

```
@available(OSX 10.12.2, *)
open override func makeTouchBar() -> NSTouchBar? {
    return AddWindowTouchBar.instanceFromNib(withWindowController: self)
}
```

That calls the following static function of my `AddWindowTouchBar` class:

```
static func instanceFromNib(withWindowController windowController: AddWindowCommon) -> AddWindowTouchBar {
        var objects = NSArray()
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(xibName, owner: windowController, topLevelObjects: &objects)

        // ...
        // return the touchbar from `objects`
        // ...

}
```

## Question

The problem here is that a class that adopts the `AddWindowCommon` protocol has its `awakeFromNib:` method called twice: a first time when it is loaded from its own `xib`, and a second time when the `AddWindowTouchBar` is instantiated using `loadNibNamed:owner:` and the window controller is the owner.

To avoid performing the tasks in `awakeFromNib:` twice, I could use a simple boolean that ensures the class hasn't been awakened from a nib yet, but I was wondering if there was another cleaner solution that acted on the `AddWindowTouchBar` rather than on the `AddWindowCommon` protocol-adopters.